# How to set the mongodb collection name when using loopback v4?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, loopback

Loopback v.4 is relatively new and I couldn't find how to modify the name of the mongodb collection here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

after sometime (try and error), found out that the collection name is exactly your model name.

the structure of the loopback 4 as far as i know:

- models

  - yourmodel.model.ts
- datasources

  - yourdatasource.datasource.ts
  - yourdatasource.datasource.json
- controllers
- repositories

i think it would be nice if they add the collection name as a field to the json file in datasource directory, since it already includes the configuration for the mongodb.

*hope this helps. thought it would be nice to have this on Stackoverflow. Please feel free to add to this answer, so it would cover more edge cases.*